# Combine elements by the key in list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following list

```
some_list = [{'key': 'YOUNG', 'x': 22, 'y': 0.9},
             {'key': 'OLD', 'x': 45, 'y': 0.6},
             {'key': 'OLD', 'x': 40, 'y': 0.3},
             {'key': 'YOUNG', 'x': 25, 'y': 0.3}]
```

and I would like to change it to:

```
[{'key': 'YOUNG', 'values': [ {'x': 25, 'y': 0.3}, {'x': 22, 'y': 0.9} ]}
 {'key': 'OLD', 'values': [ {'x': 40, 'y': 0.3}, {'x': 45, 'y': 0.6} ]}]
```

Added some of my attempts

```
arr = [{'key': 'YOUNG', 'x': 22, 'y': 0.9},
       {'key': 'OLD', 'x': 45, 'y': 0.6},
       {'key': 'OLD', 'x': 40, 'y': 0.3},
       {'key': 'YOUNG', 'x': 25, 'y': 0.3}]

all_keys = []
for item in arr:
   all_keys.append(item['key'])

all_keys = list(set(all_keys))

res = [[{
         'key': key,
         'values': {'x': each['x'], 'y': each['y']}
        } for each in arr if each['key'] == key]
       for key in all_keys]

print res
```

But the result is not right, it constructs more lists:
[[{'values': {'y': 0.6, 'x': 45}, 'key': 'OLD'}, {'values': {'y': 0.3, 'x': 40}, 'key': 'OLD'}], [{'values': {'y': 0.9, 'x': 22}, 'key': 'YOUNG'}, {'values': {'y': 0.3, 'x': 25}, 'key': 'YOUNG'}]]

Thanks.

Comment: Post your attempts..

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't so other people will write code for you. It's so other people will help you understand why you're doing something incorrectly

Comment: Pardon, I came from JavaScript world, where I can approach my goal by iterating the list and pushing to the another one.

Comment: @AvinashRaj posted, please check

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks, will do for sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loops should be like this:

```
res = [{ 'key': key,
         'values': [{'x': each['x'], 'y': each['y']} 
                    for each in arr if each['key'] == key] }
       for key in all_keys]
```

Comment: right, one more list comprehension was needed. I hope this looks like more pythonic :) Thanks!

Comment: No, I simply moved the one that was in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Using an intermediate dictionary you can do:

```
>>> temp_data = {}
>>> for x in some_list:
...     temp_data.setdefault(x['key'], []).append({k: x[k] for k in ['x', 'y']})
>>> [{'key': k, 'values': v} for k,v in temp_data.items()]
[{'key': 'OLD', 'values': [{'x': 45, 'y': 0.6}, {'x': 40, 'y': 0.3}]},
 {'key': 'YOUNG', 'values': [{'x': 22, 'y': 0.9}, {'x': 25, 'y': 0.3}]}]
```

Though personally I would just leave it in dictionary form:

```
>>> temp_data
{'OLD': [{'x': 45, 'y': 0.6}, {'x': 40, 'y': 0.3}],
 'YOUNG': [{'x': 22, 'y': 0.9}, {'x': 25, 'y': 0.3}]}
```

Comment: Right, I notice that, people from Python world use keys as keys :) but I'm using words like "key", "values" to let JS parse data easily. Maybe I should change my mind to be more Pythonic :) Thanks

Comment: BTW for a large data set, your current approach is quite inefficient O(n^2) vs O(n) above. For small datasets not really an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another try may be using `defaultdict`- It will run faster if data is larger.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
some_list = [{'key': 'YOUNG', 'x': 22, 'y': 0.9},
             {'key': 'OLD', 'x': 45, 'y': 0.6},
             {'key': 'OLD', 'x': 40, 'y': 0.3},
             {'key': 'YOUNG', 'x': 25, 'y': 0.3}]


for item in some_list:
    vals = item.copy()
    del vals['key']
    data[item['key']].append(vals)

print [{'key':k,'values':v} for k,v in data.items()]
```

Output (dictionary does not care about ordering)-

```
[{'values': [{'y': 0.6, 'x': 45}, {'y': 0.3, 'x': 40}], 'key': 'OLD'}, {'values': [{'y': 0.9, 'x': 22}, {'y': 0.3, 'x': 25}], 'key': 'YOUNG'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from  itertools import *
data =  [{'key': 'YOUNG', 'x': 22, 'y': 0.9},
             {'key': 'OLD', 'x': 45, 'y': 0.6},
             {'key': 'OLD', 'x': 40, 'y': 0.3},
             {'key': 'YOUNG', 'x': 25, 'y': 0.3}]
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['key'])
groups = []
uniquekeys = []

for k, v in groupby(data, lambda x: x['key'] ):
    val_list = []
    for each_val in v:
        val_list.append({ 'x' : each_val['x'], 'y': each_val['y']})
    groups.append(val_list)
    uniquekeys.append(k)

print uniquekeys
print groups
print zip(uniquekeys, groups)
```

You will get your output as a list of tuples where the first element is your key and the second one is the group/list of values,

```
[('OLD', [{'y': 0.6, 'x': 45}, {'y': 0.3, 'x': 40}]), ('YOUNG', [{'y': 0.9, 'x': 22}, {'y': 0.3, 'x': 25}])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
some_list = [{'key': 'YOUNG', 'x': 22, 'y': 0.9},
             {'key': 'OLD', 'x': 45, 'y': 0.6},
             {'key': 'OLD', 'x': 40, 'y': 0.3},
             {'key': 'YOUNG', 'x': 25, 'y': 0.3}]

outDict = {}

for dictionary in some_list:
    key = dictionary['key']
    copyDict = dictionary.copy()    #This leaves the original dict list unaltered
    del copyDict['key']
    if key in outDict:
        outDict[key].append(copyDict)
    else:
        outDict[key] = [copyDict]

print(outDict)
print(some_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go-

```
some_list = [{'key': 'YOUNG', 'x': 22, 'y': 0.9},
             {'key': 'OLD', 'x': 45, 'y': 0.6},
             {'key': 'OLD', 'x': 40, 'y': 0.3},
             {'key': 'YOUNG', 'x': 25, 'y': 0.3}]

dict_young_vals = []
dict_old_vals = []
for dict_step in some_list:
  temp_dict = {}
  if (dict_step['key'] == 'YOUNG'):
    for keys in dict_step.keys():
      if keys != 'key':
        temp_dict[keys] = dict_step[keys]
    if temp_dict != {}:
      dict_young_vals.append(temp_dict)
  if (dict_step['key'] == 'OLD'):
    for keys in dict_step.keys():
      if keys != 'key':
        temp_dict[keys] = dict_step[keys]
    if temp_dict != {}:
      dict_old_vals.append(temp_dict)


dict_young = {'key':'YOUNG'}
dict_young['values'] = dict_young_vals
dict_old = {'key': 'OLD'}
dict_old['values'] = dict_old_vals
print(dict_young_vals)
result_dict = []
result_dict.append(dict_young)
result_dict.append(dict_old)
print(result_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
some_list = [{'key': 'YOUNG', 'x': 22, 'y': 0.9},
         {'key': 'OLD', 'x': 45, 'y': 0.6},
         {'key': 'OLD', 'x': 40, 'y': 0.3},
         {'key': 'YOUNG', 'x': 25, 'y': 0.3}]

x=[]

for i in some_list:
    d={}
    d["key"]=i["key"]
    d["values"]=[{m:n for m,n in i.items() if m!="key"}]
    if d["key"] not in [j["key"] for j in x]:
        x.append(d)
    else:
        for k in x:
            if k["key"]==d["key"]:
                k["values"].append(d["values"][0])
print x
```

Output:`[{'values': [{'y': 0.9, 'x': 22}, {'y': 0.3, 'x': 25}], 'key': 'YOUNG'}, {'values': [{'y': 0.6, 'x': 45}, {'y': 0.3, 'x': 40}], 'key': 'OLD'}]`